# Not firing the SelectedIndexChanged when using jquery combobox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form with a `ComboBox` that provides a `dropdownlist` with loaded values from db.

Now the problem is when I am selecting a value from the combobox, the event dllTest_SelectedIndexChanged is not firing from code behind.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dllTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and I am calling the combobox from a jquery

```
$("#<%=dllTest.ClientID%>").combobox();
```

Comment: What is the use for `$("#<%=dllTest.ClientID%>").combobox();`. You are having selected index and why your are using combobox function. Could you please let me know any link for docs of combobox().

Comment: first i created a dropdownlist, and then i want that dropdownlist to be autocomplete for searching purposes. I create a javascript file named combobox which I get all the codes from jquery. That's why i use combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('#dllTest').combobox();
```

instead of:

```
$("#<%=dllTest.ClientID%>").combobox();
```

Comment: it's not getting the comboxbox style, instead it returns a dropdownlist again

Comment: also setting the property of the dropdown to ClientIDMode="Static". No luck